# How do I ignore auto complete values when capturing data from a text field?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, autocomplete

I recently implemented a search box in my site and it gives good result with auto complete of keywords.  I want to implement a hidden part to know what the search queries are that my registered visitors searched for.

I added a hidden username in the search box and when the user searches for anything, the name and search queries are saved in another table.  Because of auto complete, the data  is saved every second; so if someone searches for "Laptop", we get:

```
**ID  username  Searchdata srtime**  
1    user1234   L  1372513199            
2    user1234   La 1372513200  
3    user1234   Lap 1372513201   
4    user1234   Lapt 1372513202   
5    user1234   Lapto 1372513203  
6    user1234   Laptop 1372513204
```

jQuery code:

`$('#search_box').keyup(function() {
  // Other things 
});`

How can I save only the final search term and ignore the auto complete values?

Comment: i would set a timeout on every keyup (lets say 3-5seconds), the timeout should get reset every keyup. then you would only save after 3-5 seconds of no input. (i would use 5-10 for save the search query, and 3 for the actual search)

Comment: @x4rf41 That's a bad solution.

Comment: How about doing this on the server side? Assuming you are pulling the data from your own source..

Comment: side note: do you really need to send the username through each time, wouldn't you have access to that if they are logged in?

Comment: ok ..... I am just check Danny answer and that not worked out ,,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) instead of `.keyup()`.

This way, the data is submitted when the control loses focus, instead of every time a key is pressed.

Comment: That's impossible, unless you're submitting the data with code you haven't posted. Is the data submitted using `$('#search_box').keyup(function() {`?

Comment: You could still use keyup to do the search, but dont save at that point, and then save onBlur.

Answer (score 0):

Just Follow  these steps.

1. Save data in hidden field
2. Update hidden field on keyup.
3. Save query when user focus out from search field.

### Javascript code

> ```
> $('#search').keyup(function(){  
>     $('#searchQuery').val($('#search').val());
> });
> ```

```
$('#search').focusout(function(){  
     alert($('#searchQuery').val()); //this will return final query
 });
```

### html code

```
<input type="text" id="search">
<input type="hidden" id="searchQuery">
```